# Why TABU algorithm in bnlearn gives error for some numeric type dataset?

Tags: r, bnlearn

---

I was trying to use 'tabu' algorithm in bnlearn package in r to draw the Bayesian network. I have a data frame contains large data set and all of the columns are numeric type. I am getting the following error:

```
Error in if (abs(x1 - x2) < sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)) return(0) else return(x1 -  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I don't have any missing vales in my data set.

Here is my attempt:

```
  data = data.frame(data)
  res=tabu(data)
  graphviz.plot(res)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `tabu` work for a smaller subset of the data? Does running in `debug` mode give more info (e.g. `tabu(data, debug=TRUE)`?

Comment: Seems like the error comes from [here](https://github.com/cran/bnlearn/blob/d6a9701275a96a313e0d5132895eb29f286df18c/R/tabu.R#L74) (which calls [this funcion](https://github.com/cran/bnlearn/blob/4c0888088171d6394d377ede124d2ea6f4633117/R/utils-misc.R#L246)). Can you share some data that reproduces the error?

Comment: Some of the columns of the data set is like this: 

3.87071531 0.59429058 1.92025625 1.51485731 3 2 1.09794998 1.02479844 1.11928891
3.87071531 0.59429058 1.92025625 1.51485731 3 2 1.09794998 1.02479844 1.11928891
3.87071531 0.6225531 1.92025625 1.51485731 3 2 1.09794998 1.02479844 1.23857782
3.87071531 0.6225531 1.92025625 1.51485731 3 2 1.09794998 1.02479844 1.24125294
3.87071531 0.6225531 1.92025625 1.49999108 3 2 1.09794998 1.02479844 1.26927832
3.87071531 0.66178294 1.92025625 1.52156754 3 2 1.12173912 1.02479844 1.33426017

Comment: Its a big data set and all the variables are num type.

Comment: unfortunately that is not enough info to help figure out what is going n. From the code (at the links) it would like like a score of a network is NA for some reason -- probably need to see the data. Did running in debug give more info?

Comment: debug didnt help anything. I can send the data but I can not upload here.

Comment: str(data)
$ C1: num [1:260] 2.99 2.99 2.99 2.99 2.99 ..

 $ C2: num [1:260] 2.76 2.76 2.81 2.81 2.81 ..

 $ C3: num [1:260] 1.97 1.97 1.97 1.97 1.97 ..

 $ C4: num [1:260] 3.87 3.87 3.87 3.87 3.87 ..

 $ C5: num [1:260] 0.594 0.594 0.623 0.623 0.623 ..

 $ C6: num [1:260] 1.92 1.92 1.92 1.92 1.92 ..

 $ C7: num [1:260] 1.51 1.51 1.51 1.51 1.5 ..

 $ C8: num [1:260] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ..

 $ H1: num [1:260] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ..

 $ H2: num [1:260] 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 ..

 $ H3: num [1:260] 1.02 1.02 1.02 1.02 1.02 ..

Comment: I just observed one thing: When I make partition of the main data then the TABU do not work for the partitioned dataset.

For example:

training <- data[1:250, ]

  res=tabu(training)
  graphviz.plot(res) 

then the error is 
Error in if (abs(x1 - x2) < sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)) return(0) else return(x1 -  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

It is surprising that TABU works for data not for training. 

can you help now?

Comment: hi. Your `str` data made me look to see how `tabu` behaves with a constant as you data looks to have a lot of the same values. This throws the same error as you report: `data(gaussian.test); gaussian.test$L = 1.21 ; tabu(gaussian.test)` so I think you need to see if your training data subset has any constant columns and omit them.  I think `tabu` should give a more informative error here.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Omitting constant columns works in TABU. However, I am surprised that how other algorithm works for constant columns! 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: AKC; yes I noticed that it also worked with other algs.. I contacted the package author a couple of days ago, and they indicated that it was a bug and that they will update the code this week. Of course, if the variable is constant then no associations will be learned so really it makes no differenec if you just omit the constant variables.

Comment: Hi AKL; The [package author](https://www.bnlearn.com/about/)  has released an update; you can install it with `install.packages("https://www.bnlearn.com/releases/bnlearn_4.9-20230309.tar.gz", type="source", repos=NULL)` .  Can you check that `tabu` now runs on your data please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to a bug in `tabu`, in `bnlearn` versions <= 4.8.1, in how constant, or latent, variables were treated.

The [package author](https://www.bnlearn.com/about/)  has released an update which can be installed from the `bnlearn` website

```
install.packages("https://www.bnlearn.com/releases/bnlearn_4.9-20230309.tar.gz", type="source", repos=NULL)
```

Now the following example should run without the error observed in the OP

```
library(bnlearn)  # packageVersion("bnlearn") ‘4.9.20230309’
data(gaussian.test)
gaussian.test$L = 1.21
tabu(gaussian.test)
```